# Static translations not working on Craft 3 since upgrade from Craft 2

Tags: localization

I have upgraded from Craft2 to Craft3 and static translations no longer seem to work.

I have created a folder at the same level as the "vendor" folder called "translations" and have got a folder inside that called "en_us" (base language is en_gb). Inside that folder we have a file called "site.php" and inside that is the following:

```
<?php

return [
    '£' => '$',
    'USD' => '$',
];
```

The static translation page (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/static-translations.html) says: "..To do that, create a new folder in your project’s base directory called translations/, and within that, create a new folder named after the target language’s ID".

I assume that is a typo, but I have tried naming the folder the ID number of the site...

I've also tried renaming the folder to "en-US", "en-us" but nothing seems to work.

Code example for a translation attempt in a template: `{{ "£" | t }}`.

Any help very gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

From what i see you maybe have a typo. I think it should be `en-GB`. At least this is the folder name in the git repo : https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/69bafb027b9e2dc9c8dbede5ad6b4da2706f0650/src/translations/en-GB

Comment: I've tried that one already, didn't work either!! Thanks for the reply btw!!

Comment: Maybe try an app.php instead of site.php That was my issue a while ago.

Comment: I tried everything, nothing worked! But P&T support suggested I disable some plugin's to see if there was an issue there and that action made things work. No idea why!

Answer (score 1):

P&T support suggested I disable some plugins to see if there was an issue there and that action made things work...though no idea why really!

Comment: At least a hotfix :)
Do you know which plugin caused the error?

Comment: Well, i re-enabled them all, so, I really don't know what is going on there!